# Verificar se uma palavra está dentro de uma frase

Tags: c#, string

Há como eu verificar se uma palavra está dentro de uma frase descrita pelo usuário?

Ex:

```
palavra = "criativo";
```

Frase escrita pelo usuário:

`"Eu sou criativo"`

Comment: E se a frase fosse `Eu Sou Criativo`? Você iria querer encontrar a palavra `Criativo` com o `C` maiúsculo?

Answer (score 21):

Você pode utilizar o método [Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    string frase = "Eu sou criativo";
    string palavra = "criativo";

    if(frase.Contains(palavra))
    {
        faça algo;
    }
```

Comment: Verdade, Método String.Contains é a melhor maneira de saber se está contido a palavra `X` numa determinada string.

Comment: Pra complementar, o Contains vai chamar o IndexOf que vai acabar chamando a implementação do CLR, então as vezes é bom considerar isso.

Answer (score 6):

Além de usar o [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) para validar se uma `string` existe dentro de outra, você também pode usar [`StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx) para verificar se uma `string` começa com determinada `string`, ou o [`EndsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx) para verificar se ela termina com determinada `string`.

```
string frase = "eu sou criativo";

//Validar se contém "criativo"
if(frase.Contains("criativo")) { ... }

//Validar se começa com "criativo"
if(frase.StartsWith("criativo")) { ... }

//Validar se termina com "criativo"
if(frase.EndsWith("criativo")) { ... }
```