# Buscar item em uma lista usando LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho uma lista e quero fazer uma busca nela (como se fosse um banco de dados). É possível?

Ex: listar todos nomes da lista que iniciem por 'JOAO%'

Comment: coloca um toList() no final

Comment: era isso mesmo. consegui resolver ^^

Comment: Por favor, tente não editar suas perguntas mudando o escopo da mesma. Ainda mais quando tiver respostas já, isso acaba por invalidar as respostas existentes. Se acontecer isso novamente, você pode abrir uma nova pergunta e linkar essa daqui, assim fica mais fácil de manter as coisas organizadas.

Comment: ok, não sabia disso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Claro. Usando o método [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) do LINQ. Ele é aplicável em qualquer coleção enumerável (que implemente `IEnumerable`).

Supondo que você tenha uma lista do tipo `string`.

```
var filtrado = lista.Where(str => str.StartsWith("JOAO")).ToList();
```

Supondo que você tenha uma lista de um tipo e queira filtrar por alguma propriedade.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;

using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    static List<Cliente> listaClientes = new List<Cliente>
    {
        new Cliente { Id = 1, Nome = "Joao Carlos" },   
        new Cliente { Id = 2, Nome = "Joao Paulo" },
        new Cliente { Id = 3, Nome = "Joao da Silva" },
        new Cliente { Id = 4, Nome = "Jéferson" },
        new Cliente { Id = 5, Nome = "Joaquim" },
        new Cliente { Id = 6, Nome = "Maria Joao" },
        new Cliente { Id = 7, Nome = "Jonathan" },
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        var filtrado = listaClientes.Where(x => x.Nome.StartsWith("Joao")).ToList(); 

        foreach(var cliente in filtrado)
        {
            WriteLine($"{cliente.Nome}");   
        }
    }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no dotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ht8cpk)

---

Você pode ler [essa resposta que fala sobre o `StartsWith`, o `Contains` e o `EndsWith`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92770/18246).

Comment: estou usando assim: `var filtrado = listaCid.Where(x => x.descricao.StartsWith(txtBusca.Text)); gridCid.DataSource = filtrado;` mas o datagrid não está recebendo o resultado. estou fazendo errado?

Comment: não sei dizer se minha coleção é IEnumerable. como faço pra saber?

Comment: Não tem como eu saber. O problema pode estar em qualquer lugar. A lista `filtrado` tem algum item? Sobre "não saber se a coleção é `IEnumerable`" obviamente ela é, senão você nem teria a opção de aplicar um `Where`.

Comment: Consegui. faltava por o .ToList no final. Abraço ^^

Comment: Ótimo, boa sorte.

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa também é usar a [sintaxe de consulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/79897/27190) do Linq, ela é um pouco semelhante ao Sql, veja um exemplo:

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();
lista.Add("JOAO");
lista.Add("Maria");
lista.Add("LUCAS");

var nome = 
    (
        from n in lista 
        where n.Contains("JOAO") 
        select n
    ).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Nome: {0}", nome);
```

Saída:

> Nome: JOAO

No exemplo acima usei o método `Contains()` mas você pode substitui-lo por `StartsWith()`, desta forma vai conseguir o que deseja.

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NuDNOg).

Comment: como eu faço pra atribuir o resultado a um `dataGridView`?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo O problema é que você não está sabendo atualizar o DataGrid. Você já verificou se a lista `filtrado` tem algum item? Você sabe como fazer para trocar o DataSource de um DataGrid? Parece-me que o problema é justamente este.

Comment: realmente, ainda sou novato no VS, mas estou fazendo umas adaptações aqui pra ver se funciona. Pode me dar uma dica?

Comment: Posso, abre uma pergunta e posta o código que tu tá usando pra fazer essa atualização pra eu poder ver. @ItaloRodrigo

Comment: consegui resolver. obrigado pela ajuda